# Why jquery doesn't work on a page defined in layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `razor` layout and it loads **css jquery etc.**
When I add controller action view I set layout to be `_Layout.cshtml`
But jquery doesn't work in that page.
So I have to add `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` in each view.
Why imported jquery is not inherited from `_Layout.cshtml`? Is it normal?

Comment: This may be a dumb question but are you using the @Scripts.Render() helper in _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: You should include the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") after the @RenderBody() function! Make sure that you doing this!

Comment: `... <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` This is in layout. And when I open the page which has this layout I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be near the bottom of _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

This should be in your child view:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.js") // Or some other script
}
```

All your scripts (that reference jquery) in your child views need to be in the scripts section, not placed in the body of the page.  That includes any script tags that want to make use of jquery as well.  For example, one of my pages has the following:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false")
    <script src="~/scripts/google-maps-3-vs-1-0.js"></script>
    <script>
        Stuff here
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Although, I probably should be using @Script.Render instead of the first script tag, I was lazy when I did it.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you!I always used to move the js declaration to the top of the layout page to solve this issue but I recently learned that js needs to be at the bottom of the page for performance reasons.