# Script loaded from the _Layout not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm loading some scripts in the **_Layout.cshtml** page at the bottom of it:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

but for some reason, it won't load the jquery file. The *easing* and *bootstrap* script files will be loaded though: 
[image]

If I exclude jquery from the **_Layout.cshtml** page, it will fail to load the *easing.js* file (which was loaded previously):
[image]

I'm going nuts as I can't figure out what's going on. Does anyone ever encountered such behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found this answer to be relevant...
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860508/why-jquery-doesnt-work-on-a-page-defined-in-layout)
Use of '@section scripts' in child page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the parser is struggling with the first ~ in the list (looking at the generated path coming from Chrome.) It could be a markup error earlier in your layout file or something else entirely - hard to say with the info provided.  Typically, we use the `Url.Content()` helper instead of the raw ~ string in our script and style tags without issue.

I would recommend updating your `<script>` tags with a little bit more information.

1. Add the type to the script tag.
2. Try using the `@Url.Content()` html helper to see if that helps render the correct link.

This would be the resulting tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery bundles in BundleConfig.cs under App_Start folder ?

Comment: @Neel - yes, we have started using the bundling options in MVC this year.  However, that is a completely different call/helper to render out the bundle URL.

Comment: @Tommy: Ok, this works. The Url.Content helper fixed it (regardless of whether i specified the type of the HTML script element or not). Could you possibly explain why?

Comment: Without seeing more info, I couldn't say.  I do want to say that using ~/Path without the URL helper was an addition to one of the newer releases of the Razor view engine, so perhaps that is what is causing the issue.  Or, like I said earlier, could be a bad HTML markup somewhere?  Either way, Url.Content is the typical practice in including static content in an MVC view.

Comment: By bad markup you mean unclosed HTML tags? If yes, I've double checked it and all looks nice. Those scripts are placed right before the body closing tag ( </body> ).

Comment: See this answer to more specifically address what I said about the razor engine and update to being able to process ~ natively - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12461981/130387